# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid start or end

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce, apex

I am trying to test the Rest API Callout from Salesforce that has OAuth authentication  through the Apex code and running in to the below error
`Line: 12, Column: 1
System.UnexpectedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid start or end`

```
public with sharing class RetrieveD365Data {
    //@future (callout=true)
    public void getD365Data() {
        RetrieveAzureToken atz = new RetrieveAzureToken();
        String bearer = atz.getAzureData();
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        req1.setEndpoint('https://dev-xyz.com/data/Customers');
        req1.setMethod('GET');
        req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+bearer);
        HttpResponse res1 = http.send(req1);           //Error is thrown in this line
        System.debug('Response Body=========' + res1.getBody());
    }
}
```

Where the `RetrieveAzureToken` class is like below and this works as expected and I am able to get back the response back with the bearer token

```
global class RetrieveAzureToken {

    private final String clientId = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    private final String clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

    public String getAzureData()
    {
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/token');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        system.debug('Token from Azure :' + resp1.access_token);  
        return  resp1.access_token;
    }

    public class deserializeResponse
    {
        public String token_type;
        public String expires_in;
        public String ext_expires_in;
        public String expires_on;
        public String not_before;
        public String resource;
        public String access_token;
    }
}
```

Please let help me figure what I am missing here.

Comment: Ever worked out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

With a REST service based on Jersey and a client using HttpURLConnection I can observer the same IllegalArgumentException.

The scenario is as this:

The REST service defines a resource function

```
@GET
public void throw401() {
  throw new javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException("");
}
```

This resource is invoked by the client as

```
HttpURLConncection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
int status = c.getResponseCode(); // throws IllegalArgumentException: invalid start or end
```

The solution for me was to change the resource to:

```
@GET
public void throw401() {
  throw new javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException(Response.status(Response.UNAUTHORIZED));
}
```

I think - did not proof - the constructor NotAuthorizedException(String) generates an WWW-Authenitcate header without an authentication schema. This causes an IllegalArgumentExcption to be thrown when the HttpURLConnection tries to parse it.
The constructor NotAuthorizedException(Resonse) just sends a status 401 without a WWW-Authentication header.

Comment: Thanks for updating;
For me it was caused by a response that contained 2 WWW-Authentication headers, one empty. That causes the ex to be thrown. Unfortunately I working in Salesforce Apex, which doesn't allow java exceptions to be handled (ridiculous as it may be). So I can't handle it and my callout plain crashes. :-(